# To recover my Ubuntu data

Tags: windows-7

In my system i have install noth windows and Ubuntu. After installation of some software it shows unmet dependencies.i Just restart the computer.While log in to the Ubuntu it just showing the login page to type password of the system.After given the password it doesn't go inside it stays in log in page only.I want to recover my Ubuntu data through windows.So help me to recover this problem

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 download an application called DISK INTERNALS ... This app will allow you to access and copy files from your ubuntu installation from within Windows. I have never used this app before but I am sure it's pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: DISK INTERNALS is insufficient to read ext partitions, and always has been.

Answer (score 0):

You can live boot using USB pendrive and copy all your data from drive where you have installed ubuntu to the drive where your windows is installed. simple
tell me if you have further issues.